# CSS Scroll-Snap API?

Tags: javascript, css, dom-events

I am curious...do the CSS scroll-snap properties have a API (events) that can be hooked into via JavaScript?

I am tinkering with the idea of creating a website that uses scroll-snap to move between 100vh "slides". After each slide is done "scroll-snapping" I would like to trigger an animation.

I am sure there are crafty ways I could check each "slide" to see if it is taking 100% of the viewport, but that sort of sucks. It would be far better to fire a function after the scroll event is complete.

Here is a super simple example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  let slideNumber = $('.container > .slide').length;
  if (slideNumber > 0) {
    $('.container > .slide').each(function() {
      $('#dotNav').append('<li><a href="#slide' + $(this).index() + '"></a></li>');
    });
  }

  //DO SOMETHING AFTER SCROLL-SNAP IS COMPLETE. 
});
```

```css
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
  position: relative;
  .slide {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    background: #cccccc;
    scroll-snap-align: center;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    color: #000000;
    &:nth-child(odd) {
      background: blue;
      h2 {
        color: #ffffff;
      }
    }
    h2 {
      margin: 0;
      font-size: 40px;
      text-transform: uppercase;
    }
  }
  ul#dotNav {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    right: 20px;
    list-style: none;
    li {
      width: 20px;
      height: 20px;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
      cursor: pointer;
      a {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background: #ffffff;
        border-radius: 50%;
      }
    }
    li.active {
      background: #000000;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="slide" id="slide0">
    <h2>Slide 1</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="slide" id="slide1">
    <h2>Slide 2</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="slide" id="slide2">
    <h2>Slide 3</h2>
  </div>
  <ul id="dotNav">
  </ul>
</div>
```

You can see it working here:

https://codepen.io/trafficdaddy/pen/BMGBBg

Hope someone out there has an answer! :)

Comment: From Google developer pages: "There is an upcoming proposal to change various scrolling APIs to return a promise. This promise is resolved when user agent either completes or aborts that scrolling operation. Once this is standardized and implemented, it provides an ergonomic and efficient way for following up a user script initiated scroll with other actions." https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/07/css-scroll-snap

Comment: Well lol there ya go I guess! :) Thanks so much for finding this! I suppose I will have to play the long route until this is released.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with an [`IntersectionObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API):

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    (function scrollSpy() {
        const targets = document.querySelectorAll(".section"),
        options = {
          threshold: 0.5
        };
        // check if IntersectionObserver is supported
        if ("IntersectionObserver" in window) {
        (() => {
        const inView = target => {
        const interSecObs = new IntersectionObserver(entries => {
            entries.forEach(entry => {
            if(entry.isIntersecting) {
               fireyourfunction();
            }
            });
        }, options);
        interSecObs.observe(target);
        };
        targets.forEach(inView);
        })();
        }
    })();
});
```